# What is the minimum age of a coach in a football leagues like premiership, La Liga and Seria A

Tags: rules, football

At what age can a coach or a manager can manage a team and what is the minimum age required to be a coach in any of the following leagues?

- La Liga
- Premier League
- Serie A
- German Budesliga

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Germany (1. + 2. Bundesliga and 3. Liga) you are required to have a "Fussball-Lehrer" License, which also counts as **[UEFA Pro License](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Pro_Licence)**. This license is required in order to coach a team in the top flight domestic leagues as well as in the European competitions.

There is no direct age restriction for the Pro License, but there is one in the lower tiers of the licenses and you are required to have several years of experience in order to get there. In Germany the way up is:

(C ->) B -> Elite Youth -> A -> Fussball-Lehrer (UEFA Pro)

(You can start with B directly, if you're qualified for it)

1. You need to be at least **16 years old** in order to qualify for the C and B licenses (amateurs and youth). ([Source in German](https://www.dfb.de/sportl-strukturen/trainerausbildung/trainer-b-lizenz/))
2. You need to have worked for at least **one year** having a B license in order to qualify for [Elite Youth](https://www.dfb.de/sportl-strukturen/trainerausbildung/dfb-elite-jugend-lizenz/).
3. You need to have worked for at least **one year** with that Elite Youth license in order to qualify for the [A license](https://www.dfb.de/sportl-strukturen/trainerausbildung/trainer-a-lizenz/).
4. And for the [Pro License](https://www.dfb.de/sportl-strukturen/trainerausbildung/fussball-lehrer/) again **one year** of experience with the A license, but more restrictive (e.g. coach at least in the 6th league or youth Bundesliga or assistant coach in a pro league). If you did that already with a B license, you may get the time credited to it.

So at minimum you're **18 years** old when starting with the course (when your B license experience gets credited to your A license, otherwise you'll be 19 years old). In Germany it'll last about 10 months, so you'll probably have to add another year to it before you can start working.